# Loop through all worksheets, exclude sheets in an array from Macro

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a workbook with 45 sheets. I would like to write a code that loops through each sheet and for sheets NOT in an exclusion array, perform the task of copying the last row, pasting it to the following row, and copying over the original row as text only.

Here is the code that I have currently:

```
Sub updatereport()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne() As Variant
Dim wsName As Variant
Dim Matched As Boolean

ArrayOne = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet10", "Sheet25", "Sheet27", "Sheet41", "Sheet43", "Sheet44", "Sheet45")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Matched = False
        For Each wsName In ArrayOne
            If wsName = ws.Name Then
            Matched = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not Matched Then
    
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
    Next ws
    
    
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that this does not loop through each worksheet, it only copies the last row down 10 rows on the active worksheet. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your ranges are not qualified, so they are looking at `ActiveSheet` - Change them to `ws.Range(`

Answer (score 0):

as Brax noted, your ranges are not qualified.  There are also better approaches using variant arrays which will run much quicker than selection and pasting of ranges.  I am assuming the last row contains formulas you wish to retain, so pushing those down a row and keeping the previous row as values only.  If so, the following provides an alternative approach:

(edit - misread, that you wanted items "not" in the list.  Updated and refined).

```
Option Explicit

Sub updatereport()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ArrayOne() As Variant
Dim wsName As Variant

Dim rng1 As Variant
Dim rng2 As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long

Dim InTheList As Boolean

ArrayOne = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet3", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet10", "Sheet25", "Sheet27", "Sheet41", "Sheet43", "Sheet44", "Sheet45")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        InTheList = Not (IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, ArrayOne, 0)))
        
        If Not InTheList Then
            
            With ws
            
             lastrow = .Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
             lastcol = .Cells(lastrow, .Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            
             rng1 = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Value2 ' get values only
             rng2 = .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).FormulaR1C1 ' get any values and formulae
             
             .Range(.Cells(lastrow, 1), .Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Value2 = rng1
             .Range(.Cells(lastrow + 1, 1), .Cells(lastrow + 1, lastcol)).Formula2R1C1 = rng2
        
            End With
        End If

    Next ws
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, but I lose the cell formatting. Is there a way to retain the formatting in the new row?

Comment: copying formats are a problem with the variant arrays. It will depend on the formatting type (eg, number formats or conditional formatting, colours, etc).  One approach is to format the whole column which will apply to all rows that are copied.  A second approach (if just number formatting), is create a 3rd array and copy .NumberFormatLocal and apply it to the new range - this only works for numbers formats however.  FYI, have updated the code above to optimise further.

Answer (score 0):

This will run the code on all the sheets not named in `ArrayOne`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub updatereport()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngCopy As Range
Dim ArrayOne() As Variant
Dim Matched As Variant

    ArrayOne = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet5", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet10", _
                     "Sheet25", "Sheet27", "Sheet41", "Sheet43", "Sheet44", "Sheet45")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Matched = Application.Match(ws.Name, ArrayOne, 0)

        If Not IsError(Matched) Then
            With ws
                Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp), _
                                     .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).End(xlToRight))
                rngCopy.Copy rngCopy.Offset(1)
                rngCopy.Copy
                rngCopy.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I get 'Error 2042' as the value for the non-matched ws